# Moodle send emails on the site forum news?

Tags: email, send, moodle

Hello and thank before hand, im running `moodle 2.8` and some professor created a new site new welcoming the student and etc, then the professor wanted to know if his student received an email with the info he put in the news.

i want to know things

1. Moodle send an email every time some make a new forum in the main page(site news)?
2. if moodle does, how do i know if it failed to deliver?
3. if moodle doesn't, how can i make it to do it

every suggestion its well received.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation on Moodle notifications should help a bit https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Notifications

Also, you can get good help on the https://moodle.org/ forum.

There are two settings to consider for forum notifications: a) The forums own subscription settings, and b) the users notification settings.

**Forum subscription settings**

In Forum > Edit settings > Subscription and tracking, there is a setting for "subscription mode".

When set to "optional", users (students) can *choose* if they want to get notifications. This means they can turn notifications off and not receive any emails.

When set to "automatic", the students will be automatically subscribed to the forum notifications when they are first enrolled, but can choose to un-subscribe later (and thus not get notifications).

"Forced" subscription means students have no choice in the matter. They are subscribed to the forum notifications whether they like it or not, and the *can not* unsubscribe.

**User settings**

In each users profile, they can choose if they receive an individual email per notification, or a daily digest of either subject headings only, or full body text. Users can choose to *not* receive notifications in their profile. They can only choose *how* they receive notifications.

**News forum**

A special case exists for the "News" forum in each subject/course. All users are Forced subscription on this forum, and only Teachers or higher can post to it. It's not meant for general discussion.

**How do you know if delivery failed?**

Good question.

I'm having this issue at the moment where some users are saying they are not receiving notifications. I think looking in the server log might be the answer here, as I can't find anything inside Moodle itself that answers this question.

I'll update this answer if I find a better solution here.